# Mixtures of Dirichlet multivariates or Dirichlet processes

Tags: distributions, mixture-distribution, dirichlet-distribution, dirichlet-process

I am exploring the properties of Dirichlet distributions and their parameters. When mixing two Dirichlet distributed random bivariates
$$\mathbf{X}\equiv(X_1,X_2)\sim\text{Dir}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$$
and
$$\mathbf{Y}\equiv(Y_1,Y_2)\sim\text{Dir}(\beta_1,\beta_2)$$
does the mixture
\begin{align}
P(\cdot\mid \alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta_1,\beta_2,w_1,w_2)&=w_1 \text{Dir}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) +w_2 \text{Dir}(\beta_1,\beta_2) \\
w_1+w_2 &= 1
\end{align}
simplifies to a simpler form, for some choices of the weights for any given set of parameters $\left\{\alpha_i,\beta_i\right\}_{i=1,2}$?

Similarly, is it possible to represent a Dirichlet process mixture to with a single stochastic process?

$$w_1\text{DP}(\alpha,G)+w_2\text{DP}(\beta,G)=?$$

Both questions are motivated by the attempt to characterize the marginalization of a Dirichlet process over its concentration parameter

$$\int \text{d}\alpha \pi(\alpha) \text{DP}(\alpha,G)=?$$
by first focusing on the finite mixtures.

Comment: Do you mean a mixture or a sum? Is $w_1 X + w_2 Y$ referring to a sum of the variables or a sum of the pdf's?

Comment: I am actually interested in both, although I have edited now the question to focus on mixtures.

Comment: Since often the mixture will be multimodal, expecting any real simplification in general is going to lead to disappointment.